# How can I use ruby-progressbar in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to use [ruby-progressbar](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar) in Rails 3.2.11 for my console scripts. I added `gem 'ruby-progressbar'` to Gemfile and ran `bundle install`.

It shows `uninitialized constant ProgressBar` when I try to use it.

If I do `require 'ruby-progressbar'` it shows the following error:

`` LoadError: cannot load such file -- ruby-progressbar
from /Users/evgenyneu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require' ``

Comment: You do understand that progressbar is a text-only output that goes to the console, not to a user's browser session, right?

Comment: the Tin Man, yes, of course. I need it for my console scripts. But thanks, updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: FWIW, I use `progress_bar` gem and it's working fine.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would you check if your `bundle install` completed successfully: `gem list | grep progressbar` gives `ruby-progressbar (1.0.2)`?

Answer (score 2):

gem :
https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-progressbar

You need write some as:

```
require 'progressbar'
pbar = ProgressBar.new('data processing', some_long_data_array.length)
some_long_data_array.each do |data|
  data.process 
  pbar.inc
end
pbar.finish
```